# Read from 5x10^8 different array elements, 4 bytes each time

Tags: c++

So I'm taking an assembly course and have been tasked with making a benchmark program for my computer - needless to say, I'm a bit stuck on this particular piece.

As the title says, we're supposed to create a function to read from 5x10<sup>8</sup> different array elements, 4 bytes each time.  My only problem is, I don't even think it's possible for me to create an array of 500 million elements? So what exactly should I be doing? (For the record, I'm trying to code this in C++)

```
//Benchmark Program in C++
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    clock_t t1,t2;
    int readTemp;
    int* arr = new int[5*100000000];
    t1=clock();
    cout << "Memory Test"
         << endl;
    for(long long int j=0; j <= 500000000; j+=1)
    {
        readTemp = arr[j];
    }
    t2=clock();
    float diff ((float)t2-(float)t1);
    float seconds = diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "Time Taken: " << seconds << " seconds" <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Rough estimate:  4 * 500 million = 2 gigabytes.  Looks reasonable.

Comment: "I don't even think it's possible for me to create an array of 500 million elements?" – why not?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Well it keeps crashing at the point where I try to create the array, so I figure it's because I don't have enough memory, which seems strange.

Comment: @Axalo well they're integers so I'm assuming they're 4 bytes.

Comment: @TaiM. perhaps because you are trying to stack-allocate the thing. The stack's not gonna be enough for that; seek dynamic allocation.

Comment: Is the entire program in assembly language?  Or are pieces in assembly language?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I was figuring I'd have to make a dynamic array, but the question itself wasn't clear on that, probably should've asked in class lol

Comment: @TaiM. you do that by calling out to the OS's memory allocator. On good operating systems, it's usually called `malloc()`; on Windows, who knows what it is, but you can check MSDN's documentation.

Comment: @TaiM.In C++ you can use the `new` operator to allocate from dynamic memory.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews well I'm running into a bad_alloc() error (my code is above) do you notice anything that I missed in my code that could be causing it? (I know it has to do with memory, but I'm fairly certain I have more than enough for said array)

Comment: @TaiM. Which operating system are you using? Which compiler?

Comment: @anatolyg I'm running Windows 8.1 and the GNU GCC compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system tries to allocate 2 billion bytes (1907 MiB), while the maximum available memory for Windows is 2 gigabytes (2048 MiB). These numbers are very close. It's likely your system has allocated the remaining 141 MiB for other stuff. Even though your code is very small, OS is pretty liberal in allocation of the 2048 MiB address space, wasting large chunks for e.g. the following:

- C++ runtime (standard library and other libraries)
- Stack: OS allocates a lot of memory to support recursive functions; it doesn't matter that you don't have any
- Paddings between virtual memory pages
- Paddings used just to make specific sections of data appear at specific addresses (e.g. 0x00400000 for lowest code address, or something like that, is used in Windows)
- Padding used to [randomize the values of pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

There's a Windows [application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) that shows a memory map of a running process. You can use it by adding a delay (e.g. `getchar()`) before the allocation and looking at the largest contiguous free block of memory at that point, and which allocations prevent it from being large enough.

Comment: Thanks for this - I ended up going around to 3 different teachers trying to get it to work and nobody could figure out why it was crashing - so it's an OS problem, not a code problem.  That makes me feel *much* better.  I'll have to send this to my professor so he can know for the future.

Answer (score 0):

The size is possible :

5 * 10^8 * 4 = ~1.9 GB.

First you will need to allocate your array (dynamically only ! There's no such stack memory).

For your task the 4 bytes is the size of an interger, so you can do it

```
int* arr = new int[5*100000000];
```

Alternatively, if you want to be more precise, you can allocate it as bytes

```
int* arr = new char[5*4*100000000];
```

Next, you need to make the memory dirty (meaning write something into it) :

```
memset(arr,0,5*100000000*sizeof(int));
```

Now, you can benchmark cache misses (I'm guessing that's what it's intended in such a huge array) :

```
int randomIndex= GetRandomNumberBetween(0,5*100000000-1); // make your own random implementation
int bytes = arr[randomIndex]; // access 4 bytes through integer
```

If you want 5* 10 ^8 accesses randomly you can make a knuth shuffle inside your getRandomNumber instead of using pure random.

Comment: Well now my issue is an std::bad_alloc() error, do I actually need to use malloc() to create the array itself?

Comment: Try with lesser memory ... maybe the size is to big. New and malloc has the same effect on POD types.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up having to reduce the size and then multiply it out to get the appropriate array size.